# Problems with bool, and if statements

Tags: python

I'm building a ID Confirm system the user has 3 attempts to type the ID Correct and if not, the system will exit. And my problem is when the user is entering the correct ID at the last time the third one, when the code is correct the statement write that the ID is correct, and the second line is showing him, that he entered too many attempts and system is exiting. How can i fix the bug?
How could I fix, that when user types correct ID at the 3/3 attempt, the system would say, correct we can break the if statement. 
My code:

```
checkas = True
Attempts = 3
CurrentAttemp = 0
KickForBadCode = sys.exit
while checkas:
    CurrentAttemp += 1
    IDConfirm = input("* [3NEMATIX]: {} Please confirm Your ID CODE... Attempt! {}/{} ".format(Vartotojo_Vardas, CurrentAttemp, Attempts))
    with open (DuomenuBaz, mode = 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as Confirm:
        for line in Confirm:
            if "Vardas: "+Vartotojo_Vardas + " Password: " + Vartotojo_Pass + " ID: " + IDConfirm in line.strip():
                print("Correct!")
                Confirm.close()
                checkas = False
                break
            elif "Vardas: "+Vartotojo_Vardas + " Password: " + Vartotojo_Pass + " ID: " + IDConfirm in line.strip() and CurrentAttemp > 2:
                clear()
                print("Correct!")
                Confirm.close()
                checkas = False
                break
            elif CurrentAttemp >2:
                clear()
                print("~ You have been kicked for too many attempts!")
                checkas = False
                sys.exit
```

Comment: It is really unclear what you're asking for, please try to edit your question to be more clear.

Comment: I think the question is explicit said, how can I fix the bug.

Comment: question? sample data?

Comment: How could I fix, that when user types correct ID at the 3/3 attempt, the system would say, correct we can break the if statement.

Comment: If you want to call `sys.exit` you need to write it as `sys.exit()`.

Comment: Thats not the question

Answer (score 1):

You need to `exit` only when the `CurrentAttemp` is `>` than `Attempts`. and if the `Vartotojo_Pass` is correct in `<=` to `Attempts`.

Try replacing this part:

```
if "Vardas: "+Vartotojo_Vardas + " Password: " + Vartotojo_Pass + " ID: " + IDConfirm in line.strip():
                print("Correct!")
                Confirm.close()
                checkas = False
                break
            elif "Vardas: "+Vartotojo_Vardas + " Password: " + Vartotojo_Pass + " ID: " + IDConfirm in line.strip() and CurrentAttemp > 2:
                clear()
                print("Correct!")
                Confirm.close()
                checkas = False
                break
            elif CurrentAttemp >2:
                clear()
                print("~ You have been kicked for too many attempts!")
                checkas = False
                sys.exit
```

With this:

```
        if "Vardas: "+Vartotojo_Vardas + " Password: " + Vartotojo_Pass + " ID: " + IDConfirm in line.strip():
            print("Correct!")
            Confirm.close()
            checkas = False
            break
        elif "Vardas: "+Vartotojo_Vardas + " Password: " + Vartotojo_Pass + " ID: " + IDConfirm in line.strip() and CurrentAttemp < Attempts:
            clear()
            print("Correct!")
            Confirm.close()
            checkas = False
            break
        elif CurrentAttemp > Attempts:
            clear()
            print("~ You have been kicked for too many attempts!")
            checkas = False
            sys.exit
```

Comment: Now the user can do 4 attemps, and if the last attempt is correct. Terminal:
~ You have been kicked for too many attempts!
Correct!

Comment: @nematixPY try replacing now. `CurrentAttemp < Attempts`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, it had too many if statements, that caused the script to re-bool everytime, and script was not going to functionate. The problem, was only the if statements.

```
 checkas = True
    Attempts = 3
    CurrentAttemp = 0
    KickForBadCode = sys.exit
    while checkas:
        CurrentAttemp += 1
        if CurrentAttemp > 3:
            checkas = False
            clear()
            print("~ You have been kicked for too many attempts!")
            sys.exit
        else:
            IDConfirm = input("* [3NEMATIX]: {} Please confirm Your ID CODE... Attempt! {}/{} ".format(Vartotojo_Vardas, CurrentAttemp, Attempts))
            with open (DuomenuBaz, mode = 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as Confirm:
                for line in Confirm:
                    if "Vardas: "+Vartotojo_Vardas + " Password: " + Vartotojo_Pass + " ID: " + IDConfirm in line.strip():
                        print("Correct!")
                        Confirm.close()
                        checkas = False
                        break
                    else:
                        checkas = True
                        clear()
```